# mySQL: getting the rest of a row's data when using 'max'

Tags: mysql

I have a table that looks a bit like this:

```
user_id   item_id   bid_amount
5         12        22
6         12        47
7         12        40
6         14        55
```

I'm trying to get the highest bid for a each item and the user_id which belongs to that bid. My current attempt:

```
select user_id, max(bid_amount) from bids group by item_id;
```

fails pretty spectacularly. I think its just the user_id from the first row int he group -- is there a single query that gets me the data I want?

Comment: What should happen if there are two or more users with the same bid for an item? Or is that impossible?

Comment: its impossible so your solution works correctly -- thank you so much. Now i need to do some thinking so I can understand why it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT user_id, item_id, bid_amount FROM bids 
WHERE (item_id, bid_amount) IN (
   SELECT item_id, MAX(bid_amount) FROM bids GROUP BY item_id
)
```

See it working online: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f62a5/3)

Comment: haven't seen sqlfiddle before -- very nice!